# datareader doesn't read data

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have a bit of an issue but I can't figure out the problem. So I have a `DataReader` where I read my data from my database. But the problem is despite having a matching row in my database, the `DataReader` keeps coming back with no rows.

my database connection:

```
static private String _connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=dboVids;User id=g;password=g;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False";  
        static private SqlConnection _connection;

        static Connection()
        {
            try
            {
                _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                switch (ex.HResult)
                {
                    default:
                        throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

my method:

```
static public SqlDataReader WeergevenRolPerUser(string userName)
            {
                try
                {
                    Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[fnShowDatabaseRole]('@UserName')", _connection);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
                    SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    myReader.Read();
                    return myReader;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    switch (ex.HResult)
                    {
                        default:
                            throw;
                    }
                }
            }
```

the `Open()` method:

```
private static void Open()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    _connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                switch (ex.HResult)
                {
                    default:
                        throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

here is where I call the `DataReader`:

```
 private void lstUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                if (_username != "" && lstUsers.SelectedValue != null)
                {
                    string user = lstUsers.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    reader = Database.Users.WeergevenRolPerUser(user);

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("unreachable");
                        var rol = reader.GetString(0);
                        if (rol == "gebruiker")
                        {
                            rdbUser.Checked = true;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                switch (ex.HResult)
                {
                    default:
                        throw;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null) reader.Close();
            }


        }
```

Comment: Not enough info. Normally, you'd use Profiler to watch your sql command hit the database, so you know *exactly* what the actual query is (not what you assume it is), then you take that and execute it on your database to see what you *actually* get back. That's usually enough to tell you what's going on 90% of the time

Comment: Does the query return results when you execute it in the database? Can you debug the application without any exceptions being thrown? Also you should use _using_-Blocks. Currently you aren't closing the connections.

Comment: It's usually a *bad* idea to have a shared `Connection` object - share the connection *string* but create new `Connection` objects for each `Command` that needs one (and make sure you wrap them in `using` or `Dispose` of them after use).

Comment: exactly, avoid sharing connections, even readers. Don't let your data layer code mix with the UI code, it's very bad practice. Makes your code terrible to read and understand. Not to mention the complexities with leaving a connection open longer than needed, synchronizing events, managing state. Zillion things to go wrong!

Comment: I don't really understand what u guys mean with sharing connections. What do u recommend I should do then. I'm complete newbie in programming. Could u give me an example what the proper way should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are calling `.Read()` twice on the reader object, which, as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Advances the SqlDataReader to the next record.

You do this once in `WeergevenRolPerUser` which will read the data you are expecting to be returned, and once again in `lstUsers_SelectedIndexChanged` which as you are finding, won't read anything, because there is no next record to advance to.

If I were you, I would change `WeergevenRolPerUser` to return a `User` object.

```
static public User WeergevenRolPerUser(string userName)
{
    try
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection string */))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using(var command = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[fnShowDatabaseRole]('@UserName')", connection))
            {
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);

                 using(var myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     while(myReader.Read())
                     {
                         return new User
                                {
                                     Username = myReader.GetString(/* column index */),
                                     Role = myReader.GetString(/* column index */)
                                }
                     }
                 }

                 myReader.Close();
             }
         }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems entirely plausible. I would also note that OP's mixing of list view events with database code and keeping the db connection open for longer than needed is extremely bad practice

Comment: What exception? Bear in mind you'll have create a new class called `User` with the properties you need, and you'll need to supply the correct index of the column with the data in you want.

Comment: "executereader requires an open and available connection. the connection's current state is closed"

Comment: Ah my bad, I'm missing `connection.Open()` before passing it to the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: stupid question but where do I need to put connection.Open() ? It gives me a lot of errors if I put it in the using

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer. None of that is tested, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok thank you! Last question should i remove my `Open()` method and instead use `using(var connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection string */))` for every method?

Comment: You'll probably want to change your `Open()` method to return a new, open, connection object, and use that in the `using`: `using(var connection = Open())....`.
Also, if this answer has helped, it would be great to mark it as the accepted answer :)