# Retrieved data not read in while loop using SQLiteDataReader.Read() method in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datareader

`SQLiteDataReader.Read()` doesn't reply with false even though it contains data.

1. I have been running tests on some data controllers, but every time I retrieve data from the db it does not work for some reason, to be exact, Read() doesn't enter the loop to read the data in it.
2. Connection was successful, data has been read, and I have observed it in the debugger, please see the screenshot below.

The following code is what I'm doing, expected to enter the while loop in the try block.

```
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = null;
        //Make sure to ignore class names below, the problem isn't related to them they are changed for sake of demonstration
        Dictionary<string, SomeDTO> output = new Dictionary<string, SomeDTO>();

        try
        {
            command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM {TableName}";
            
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            { //This loop is never entered
                output.Add(reader.GetString(0), ConvertReaderToObject(reader));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("SOME-LOG IRRELEVANT"+ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

In the picture below you can see debugger details on the reader object, data was read as expected...
[image: proof data was read]

I have reviewed these questions but couldn't find the answer there:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454131/whilereader-read-function-not-working-mysql-c-sharp), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215129/datareader-doesnt-read-data), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215129/datareader-doesnt-read-data)

Comment: What is exactly your connectionstring?

Comment: I have mentioned the connection is ok but yeah here it is: `path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "database.db"));
            connectionString = $"Data source={path}; Version=3; New=false;";`

Comment: OK, so are you aware that when you run the app inside VS the current directory is BIN\DEBUG or BIN\x86\DEBUG? Did you check if the database in that path has records?

Comment: Yes I am, the the database in both is identical, additionally I showed that the data I expected to get was observed in the debugger `reader` object

Comment: Did you try it without the debugger? If you are expanding the result view you are enumerating all records, after that you will not enter the loop.  What is `ConvertReaderToObject`? Maybe you encounter an error. Have you set a breakpoint in the catch?

Comment: I did try running release @TimSchmelter, though with the same issue happening, no data was loaded to the dict.

Comment: @study.isLove: it's not about running in debug or release mode, it's about using the debugger to inspect the reader which will enumerate the records and "consume" the reader, so you won't enter the loop. Just run with a breakpoint in the catch. I'm pretty sure that you get an exception.

Comment: Expanding the view in the debugger will read the results, so you won't have any to read anymore. Side notes: you should dispose your objects with `using`, you don't need that whole `finally` logic. Do not inject object names unless you are *sure* they are safe.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see ty! I think it's that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TimSchmelter answer, posting to resolve so question won't drive attention to it.
The debugger itself consumes the data in `reader`, thus I can see the data in the debugger. Debugging straight from the catch, will show I had an exception inside the while loop.

Comment: Answers are not for conversation. And if someone else has helped you solve your problem, ask them in comments to post their solution as an answer so that you can accept their solution and they can be rewarded for helping you.